# CentOS 8 dbus-daemon stops selinux enforcing for a few minutes then returns to enforcing

Tags: security, centos, selinux

I am having a problem I have spent multiple days searching for an answer to.  I administer a system running CentOS 8 (yes, I know, move to another distribution - we are within the month).  The problem I am having is that if I do an "ausearch -m AVC,USER_AVC,SELINUX_ERR -ts today" I find that the system's dbus-daemon is found to do this: "msg='avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=0)  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon"".  A few minutes later (like 2 and a half minutes), the daemon does this: " msg='avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon"".
I cannot find any references on the net to any daemon that does this and it concerns me that it may be a security failure of which our company does the best it can to eliminate.  Can anyone enlighten me as to what is happening?